# Are there any tutorial/guides to use firebug?

Tags: firebug

I just got the add-on for firefox and it's awesome so far! But all I am doing is just moving the cursor around the page to get the css+html. And I know there are TONS more applications to firebug. Is there a beginner's guide to firebug since it's so popular or is it just something with practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the [Firebug Wiki](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)? Lots of resources on there about how to use it, including an introductory video.

Comment: ah I failed to see that. I'll look into it!

Answer (score 2):

That can be useful : http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/screencast/firebug-js/